# map the min command to a multilevel list in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I want to find the smallest values in a set of lists

```
map min [[1, 3], [2, 7],[9, 6]]
```

I would like this to output

```
[[1],[2],[6]]
```

It gives the error:

```
* No instance for (Show ([Integer] -> [Integer]))
arising from a use of `print'
(maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
* In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**`min :: Ord a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:min) works on two items to return the minimum of the two. You are probably looking for [**`minimum :: (Foldable f, Ord a) => f a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:minimum) instead:

```
Prelude> map minimum [[1, 3], [2, 7],[9, 6]]
[1,2,6]
```

Here the items are not wrapped in individual sublists, but that would only result in an (unnecessary) extra layer of indirection.